# Rails undefined variable @assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this  [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940)

My error is @asset variable which I am using in my _form.html.erb and index.html.erb is not working .It is saying **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**
.But when I replace it will :asset_path then it starts working

[assets_controller]

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!  #authenticate for users before any methods is called 


  def index 
    @assets = current_user.assets      
  end



  def new
    @asset = current_user.assets.new
  end

  def create 
    @asset = current_user.assets.new(user_assets) 

  end




private
    def user_assets
         params.require(:asset).permit(:user_id, :uploaded_file)
    end

end
```

[assets/_form.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @assets, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
  <%= f.error_messages %> 

    <p> 
        <%= f.label :uploaded_file, "File" %><br /> 
        <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %> 
      </p> 
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload" %></p> 
<% end %>
```

[index.html.erb]

```
  <% title "Assets" %> 
    <table> 
      <tr> 
        <th>Uploaded Files</th> 
      </tr> 

      <% for asset in @assets %> 

        <tr> 
          <td><%= link_to asset.uploaded_file_file_name, asset.uploaded_file.url %></td> 
          <td><%= link_to "Show", asset %></td> 
          <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_asset_path(asset) %></td> 
          <td><%= link_to "Destroy", asset, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td> 
        </tr> 
      <% end %> 
    </table> 
    <p><%= link_to "New Asset", new_asset_path %></p>
```

[rake routes]

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                              homes#index
                  assets GET    /assets(.:format)              assets#index
                         POST   /assets(.:format)              assets#create
               new_asset GET    /assets/new(.:format)          assets#new
              edit_asset GET    /assets/:id/edit(.:format)     assets#edit
                   asset GET    /assets/:id(.:format)          assets#show
                         PATCH  /assets/:id(.:format)          assets#update
                         PUT    /assets/:id(.:format)          assets#update
                         DELETE /assets/:id(.:format)          assets#destroy
```

Comment: You need to remove this line `<% @assets=:assets_path%>`

Comment: assets_path is a `helper method`. Why you are treating it as symbol?

Comment: oh it was mistake...I have already remove that line ...my error is basically when I am using :assets_path it is working but when i am using instance variable it is not working

Comment: Where? What instance variable? Be specific.

Comment: I am using assets_path because I have that method ...i Have updated my rake routes

Comment: If you see my _form.html.erb and index.html.erb page there I am using @assets instance variable so its not working

Comment: i need to specify my full path like :assets_path ...which i don't want to do

Comment: You should remove anything not related to the problem (such as, probably, show, new, delete, … methods, routes not used in this example, …) and tell us exactly what you mean by “not working.” What behavior did you expect, what did you see instead? What exactly did you try that made an observable difference, and what was that difference?

Comment: ok let me update my question

Comment: sir is my doubt clear or Do i need to update again?

Comment: `@asset` not `@assets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#assets/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @asset, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

---

If you use [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), you have to pass a valid object type. Typically, this is done with a variable (as above), but it can be with a symbol.

The `form_for` method infers the other form attributes (`path` etc) from this initial value, hence you need to have an initial value for it.

--

The issue you have is that for your *new* method, you've declared `@asset`, yet are using `@assets` in your `form_for`. Standard undeclared / nil variable problem unfortunately.